# bootstrap sass 2 -- custom.css.scss.css 404 not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not able to get the bootstrap sass 2.0.0 to work with rails. The application layout does not change even after following the tutorial of Micheal Hartl which is by using rails 3.2. I have tried all the possible changes.

```
Started GET "/assets/custom.css.scss.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-26 03:42:45 +0300
Served asset /custom.css.scss.css - 404 Not Found (7ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/custom.css.scss.css"):
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

This is the thing which comes when run the rails server:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-26 03:42:45 +0300
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-05-26 03:42:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-leng
th of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-26 03:42:45 +0300
Served asset /rails.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-05-26 03:42:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-leng
th of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file to `custom.css.scss`

Comment: once i renamed my server keeps exiting...here this wat it shhows now ;